# useEffect() TypeError: e is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, use-effect

I'm getting `TypeError: e is not a function`

at MessagePort.C.port1.onmessage (react.production.min.js:24)

for reasons that I do not understand in a useEffect(). I realize this is probably an obscure problem relative to my codebase seeing as I cannot replicate in codesandbox but figured I'd throw this up anyhow.

```js
useEffect(() => someVar && console.log('asdf'), [button])
```

It seems to work when I simply put the function in a block

```js
useEffect(() => {if (someVar) console.log('asdf')}, [button])
```

Comment: You are not sharing the whole picture, I guess you running some code in the cleaning up function of useEffect which causes the problem. Anyway this example will get only a warning and not a runtime error.

Comment: I guess this one "someVar" is a function where is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first assumption is that you are not really meaning to return from the `useEffect`, but were mis-using the short hand syntax and didn't realize it uses an implicit return ([read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) about arrow functions and implicit returns).

The returned function from `useEffect` will run as a cleanup (as mentioned in the comments). What you are returning from the effect will depend on the condition, but in neither case will it return a function. If `someVar` is falsy it will return `someVar`. If `someVar` is truthy, it will return the value of `console.log()` which is `undefined`.

See below what happens when a `useEffect` returns `false` (click the "unmount" button to see the effect).

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
   
   return (
    <div>
      {toggle ? <Child /> : null}
      <button onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}>unmount</button>
    </div>)
}
const Child = () => {
   useEffect(() => false);
   
   return <span />
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

You should always use the long hand form of an arrow function when using an effect, unless you only intend to pass it a cleanup.

Comment: Good catch! Forgot to unmount on my checkings -_-, this definitely should be an issue on React github, the cleaning function should check if the callback is a function.

Comment: Based on the warning image the OP posted as an answer, I think it already does that. It just only warns, and does not stop execution of the bad code.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect expect a clean-up function to be returned, an alternative of componentWillUnmount() lifecycle, but it is optional.
So it throw error because `someVar && console.log('asdf')` is not a function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (someVar) console.log('asdf');

  return () => {
    // do something while leaving this component.
  };
}, [button)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: Did you try it? Not returning a function will leave a warning, but not a runtime error...

Comment: @DennisVash If you return false from a `useEffect`  it does. It will attempt to do `false()` and break.

Comment: I checked it, it didn't break in production and in development, did you check it?

Comment: Yes I did. I got `d is not a function`.

Comment: @DennisVash added an answer with running example

Answer (score -1):

I overrode the react-dom and react packages to development and here we are. I was returning a boolean in the fn provided to useEffect. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-pine-q0edp?file=/src/App.js)

[image]

Comment: Thats a warning. Not a runtime error like in your question, also you should edit the question instead of answering with more details.

Comment: This leads to the runtime error. See codesandbox and click button. Sorry didn't realize that. Will do so in future. Seems weird there is UX to let OP answer.

Comment: It **DOES NOT** lead to runtime error. Your specific code in your codebase does. To be sure I checked myself.

Comment: Well yeah I mean isn't that the point? My question was why this runtime error was happening with my useEffect. If this was a problem with react I would post it on github. I was trying to figure out why my use of react was wrong and I did. Return an actual fn.